# fping with timestamp logging to file named with date

Tags: command-line, networking, ping

**Hello.**
Using my server to log network DC's that seem to occur sporadicly during the days.
Looked around and collected code and got this to work, wich i launch via cronjob to get one textfile a day.

**The program:**

```
#!/bin/bash

## Get current date ##
_now=$(date +"%d_%m_%Y")

## Appending a current date from a $_now to a filename stored in $_file ##
_file="/path/to/file/pinglogger_$_now.txt"

## fping 24h with timestamp to a file with todays date ##
fping -c 86000 -s google.com 192.168.250.1 | while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong"; done > "$_file" 2>&1
```

**The problem:**
This works, **but i do not get the last lines of ping statistics when the program ends.** Problem started when i found and added `| while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong"; done` to the program to add timestamp on the pings.

**The soultion:**
After tips and trix, final code is this and it writes stout and sterr to output file: pings local host and google for approx 1 day to a file with todays date.:

```
#!/bin/bash

## Get current date ##
_now=$(date +"%d_%m_%Y")

## Appending a current date from a $_now to a filename stored in $_file ##
_file="/path to file/pinglogger_$_now.txt"

## fping 24h with timestamp to a file with todays date ##
(fping -c 86000 -s google.com 192.168.250.1 | ts) &> "$_file"
```

Comment: Your `2>&1` only applies to the RHS of the pipe, which only `read`s fping's stdout. Try moving it to the LHS i.e. `fping -c 86000 -s google.com 192.168.250.1 2>&1 | while read ... > "$_file"`

Comment: adding time to a command you can do `command | ts`

Comment: @steeldriver Actually helped to add a line on the LHS, now the error's is logged for request timeouts and so on. But i am still missing the last lines with the summary of the fping and stats from -s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using TS to short it down and putting code in () piping bot sterr and stout to file worked.

`(fping -c 86000 -s google.com 192.168.250.1 | ts) &> "$_file"`